# ¿Cómo imprimir el número de palabras dentro de un camelCase?

Tags: c++

Se supone que lo que hace es que, al meter en el arreglo, agrega +1 a una variable con mayúscula, que significa el numero de palabras.:.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int contarpalabras(char[]);

int main()
{
    int tam = 50;
    char palabras[tam];

    cout << "Introduce tu texto camelCase: ";
    cin >> palabras[tam];

    cout << "Tu texto tiene " << contarpalabras(palabras) << "palabras" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int contarpalabras(char *palabras[], int *tam)
{
    int p;
    int tam2 = *tam;

    for(int i=0;i < tam2;i++)
    {
        if(*palabras[i] <= 91)
        {
            p++;
        }

    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Este código ni siquiera compila. Deberías empezar por ahí. http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: O hacer referencia a que el error es, precisamente, que no compila. Das a entender que *no funciona como debiera*.

Comment: Te aconsejo que a la hora de preguntar en este foro te tomes tu tiempo para redactar tu pregunta correctamente., explicando bien que se pretende hacer y que no funciona. Tu código tiene problemas graves, para empezar el prototipo de tu función `contarpalabras()` no se corresponde con la que luego declaras. Por otro lado `cin >> palabras[tam];` está mal, debe ser: `cin >> palabras;` En cuanto a la función en si solo tienes que recorrer la cadena (o el puntero) y buscar las mayusculas. Intentalo, que al menos compile y si no edita la pregunta y te ayudo .

Answer (score 1):

Es bastante sencillo, usa [`std::count_if`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) junto [`std::isupper`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper):

```
constexpr char texto[]{"enUnLugarDeLaManchaDeCuyoNombreNoQuieroAcordarmeNoHaMuchoTiempoQueVivíaUnHidalgoDeLosDeLanzaEnAstilleroAdargaAntiguaRocínFlacoYGalgoCorredor."};

auto p = std::count_if(std::begin(texto), std::end(texto),
                       [](char c){ return std::isupper(c); });
```

Si es camelCase tendrás que sumar 1 al resultado, si es UpperCamelCase no será necesario.

Comment: Te puedes ahorrar la lambda: `std::count_if(std::begin(texto), std::end(texto),::isupper);` ;)

Comment: ¡Cierto! :D pero es que las lambdas son taaaaaaaaaaan bonitas <3

Comment: te entiendo perfectamente

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es algo como esto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int contarpalabras(string);

int main()
{
    string palabras;

    cout << "Introduce tu texto camelCase: ";
    cin >> palabras;

    cout << "Tu texto tiene " << contarpalabras(palabras) << " palabras" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int contarpalabras(string palabras)
{
    int numeroPalabras = 1;

    for(int i=0;i < palabras.length();i++)
    {
        if(palabras[i] < 91 and palabras[i] > 64) //ASCII para mayusculas
        {
            numeroPalabras++;
        }
    }
    return numeroPalabras;
}
```

Este código si compila y funciona.

Ejemplo:

Input: `variableUnoDosTres`

Output: `Tu texto tiene 4 palabras`